# Why is PHP selecting the Random Values like that?

Tags: php, arrays, random, undefined-behavior

So... I was testing something and noticed that when I run this code:

```
$arr = str_split("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890", 1);
print_r(implode(array_rand(array_flip($arr), 16)));
```

The Output is

```
Refresh 1: BDFIJKPTVkl12789
Refresh 2: HIJKMQWYdfmorsw3
Refresh 3: FGHMNRVYfhknouw5
Refresh 4: AFIJKRSVeiuwx579
Refresh 5: DJORYZcgijlpqry1
Refresh 6: EISWbhjmoqr45689
Refresh 7: CDEFOTXdhkloqr27
Refresh 8: AEFIKLNORSknx349
Refresh 9: DEFHJMTVZcgpstz0
Refresh 10: CLQTZbefhnpq1279
```

> Why does the output start everytime with 1 to 5 uppercase letters?
>   That "randomness" seems weird to me.

I would like to know why I get this result.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[`array_rand`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php) (since PHP 5.2.10) no longer shuffles the list of random keys that it generates (you'll notice that your output strings are all in alphabetical order i.e. the characters are in the same order as they are in the input string). If you don't want that behaviour, use [`shuffle`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php) and [`array_slice`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) instead:

```
$arr = str_split("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890", 1);
shuffle($arr);
echo implode('', array_slice($arr, 0, 16));
```

Output:

```
dU54f9wBjZbAKgCP
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/XLlI2)

Comment: Plus one to this guy. For some reasons, PHP devs removed shuffle behavior in 5.2.10.

Comment: @user1597430 yeah - a weird thing to do since using something with the name `rand` in it kind of implies you want something random... I'll update my answer with that info.

Comment: @Nick thats what i mean. It has a strange behavior... I wonder why that is. I love to know because knowing how you use it and knowing how it works is something different

Comment: @Justin99b I updated my answer, if you look at the [array_rand manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php) you'll see that the list of keys it generates is no longer random (since PHP 5.2.10)

Comment: @Justin99b as for why, you'd have to ask the PHP developers or look at the [PHP source code](https://github.com/php/php-src)

Comment: @Nick oooh okay that makes sense. Well thanks. I Actually didnt know something important like this is under the Changelog. I guess i lerned today that you sometimes need to look into the changelog ^^. I Appreciate the time you spend to Answere my Question. Thanks and have a nice day :)